# How to export chart with custom html section in highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

I've implemented a chart like [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/meysamm22/quf2n608/1/), and I want to export the chart with the `div` which is located next to the chart and contains map help table. how is it possible?

```
<div id="container"></div>
<div id="map-help">
 <p>
  hello world
 </p>
</div>

Highcharts.ganttChart('container', {
    title: {
        text: 'Gantt Chart with Progress Indicators'
    },
    xAxis: {
        min: Date.UTC(2014, 10, 17),
        max: Date.UTC(2014, 10, 30)
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Project 1',
        data: [{
            name: 'Start prototype',
            start: Date.UTC(2014, 10, 18),
            end: Date.UTC(2014, 10, 25),
            completed: 0.25
        }, {
            name: 'Test prototype',
            start: Date.UTC(2014, 10, 27),
            end: Date.UTC(2014, 10, 29)
        }, {
            name: 'Develop',
            start: Date.UTC(2014, 10, 20),
            end: Date.UTC(2014, 10, 25),
            completed: {
                amount: 0.12,
                fill: '#fa0'
            }
        }, {
            name: 'Run acceptance tests',
            start: Date.UTC(2014, 10, 23),
            end: Date.UTC(2014, 10, 26)
        }]
    }]
});
```

Comment: Take a look at this topics: https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=31048 https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=35328 https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=37119

Comment: @SebastianWędzel thanks for your comment, The solution which mentioned in the second link (this one: http://jsfiddle.net/gd7bB/2460/) seems appropriate, but how can I change it to offline-exporting?

Comment: @MeysamZarei here you can see an example of a demo that uses offline - everything is done on the client-side: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/p1njb274/